# RubyMine debugger debase LoadError

Tags: ruby, rubymine

A few months ago RubyMine's debugging functionality suddenly break down.
When I run debugger I see the following error message:

> /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/rb/gems/debug_preloader.rb:4:in
>   require': cannot load such file -- debase (LoadError)
>        from /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/rb/gems/debug_preloader.rb:4:in
>   '
>       from -e:1:in `require'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I reinstalled rbenv, ruby 2.0.0-p645, bundler 1.9.4 and rails. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RubyMine team has responded that this will be fixed in the future release.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-18728

Two temporary fixes have been suggested:

> 1. Upgrade your Ruby version, since https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/02/24/support-plan-of-ruby-2-0-0-and-2-1/
> 2. Change your Ruby version manager to RVM, debase works fine with it.